# Get "Custom id" for ItemStack in bukkit

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

firstly I want to apologize for my very bad English xD. So, I'm developing an economy plugin just to learn and in this plugin, I'm creating a sign shop. Everything was going fine, but when I was trying my shop, **I got stuck with enchanted items, for example, because I can't get the id with only:**

```java
ItemStack item = player.getItemInHand();
item.getTypeId();
```

This only returns me the id of the real item, without enchantment.
Someone can tell me if Has a method I can make to set some *custom id*, in the lore of item, for example, that I can use later to make a sign shop?

EDIT:

Now works fine to save item data, but still giving error.
What i'm using now is:

```
public static void saveItem(Player player){
    ItemStack item = player.getItemInHand();
    //config.createSection("eco.sell.aFirstItem");
    ConfigurationSection configToEdit = config.createSection("eco.sell.aFirstItem");
    configToEdit.set("type", item.getType().name());
    configToEdit.set("amount", item.getAmount());
    if(item.hasItemMeta()){
        ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
        configToEdit.set("meta.name", meta.getDisplayName());
        List<String> enchants = new ArrayList<>();
        meta.getEnchants().forEach((en, lvl) -> enchants.add(en.getName() + ":" + lvl));
        configToEdit.set("meta.enchant", enchants);
        save();

    }
}
```

So, to restore data i'm using:

```
public static void restoreData(Player player){
    //config.getConfigurationSection("eco.sell.aFirstItem");
    ConfigurationSection configToEdit = config.createSection("eco.sell.aFirstItem");
    ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.valueOf(configToEdit.getString("type")), configToEdit.getInt("amount")); 

    if(configToEdit.contains("meta")) {
        player.sendMessage("Contains( Meta )");
        ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName(configToEdit.getString("meta.name"));
        List<String> enchants = configToEdit.getStringList("meta.enchants"); 
        enchants.forEach(line -> {
            String[] split = line.split(":"); 
            item.addEnchantment(Enchantment.getByName(split[0]), Integer.parseInt(split[1]));

        });

    }
    player.getInventory().addItem(item);
    player.updateInventory();
}
```

Comment: The question is ambiguous to me, what exactly are you trying to do? Add a way to identify specific items or get enchants from a specific item?

Comment: Yes, something like that. To  be more specific, I want to do something like the /iinfo command of the ChestShop plugin, do you know?  But I want to identify the item with some enchant,  for example, and take it  from a sign to make a shop sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a unique ID like that.

But, there is two ways :

1. Store full object. For example, create a json that contains the item id, item name, enchants... Then store it as you want to save ids.

For example, we will save an item and restore it. We will use the default config of spigot.

**Save the item**

```java
Configuration objConfig = plugin.getConfig().createSection("eco.sell.aFirstItem"); // create new section in plugin config
// now we will add all content from item to config
objConfig.set("type", item.getType().name()); // item type
objConfig.set("amount", item.getAmount()); // amount of item
if(item.hasMetadata()) {
   ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
   objConfig.set("meta.name", meta.getDisplayName()); // item name
   List<String> enchants = new ArrayList<>(); // create hashmap that will be saved
   meta.getEnchants().forEach((en, lvl) -> enchants.add(en.name() + ":" + lvl));
   objConfig.set("meta.enchants", enchants); // all items enchants
}
plugin.saveConfig();
```

Now, we will **restore data from config** :

```java
Configuration objConfig = plugin.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("eco.sell.aFirstItem"); // retrieve section
ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.valueOf(objConfig.getString("type")), objConfig.getInt("amount")); // here we have an item that we can edit
if(objConfig.contains("meta")) {
   ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
   meta.setDisplayName(objConfig.getString("meta.name"));
   List<String> enchants = objConfig.getStringList("meta.enchants"); // get all enchants
   enchants.forEach(line -> {
      String[] split = line.split(":"); // split enchantName:enchantLevel
      item.addEnchant(Enchantement.valueOf(split[0]), Integer.parse(split[1])); // get spigot objects
   });
}
```

Warn: few line can don't work because I don't test this exact code, but that's how it should work.

2. Create a list of items which have an ID, then refer this id where you want. And you just have to make the link between both (such as SQL database works).

The second can be useful if you always are selling same items. I think in your case the first solution will be better.

Comment: So, I was trying to do the first, but, i don't know if I can "set an id" for an enchanted item, it's possible? Or i'll have to make... i don't know, some kind of invisible lore to identify this item later?

The second way I think I can do too, but, is the same question of the first, I can get this item id later in the sign using methods like, Material.GetMaterial();???

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can just use `name()` and `valueOf()` to save and get data like the material name of enchant name. I will add a full example for the first one

Comment: I'm trying this method here, but, "forEach(en, lvl -> enchants.add(en.name()" is giving  me an error, BitConsumer "en", is not found, but, "lvl" is. I have to create an hashmap before?

Comment: I think you are iterating on wrong field. The method `getEnchants` of item meta return a map

Comment: Oh yes sorry, it's my fault. it's Java wrong typo, we have to add "()" when there is at 2 or more args on lambda expression

Comment: Don't worry, it's fine, I have to add "()" in front of "en"?

Comment: I edited my answer. It's like "(en, lvl)->"

Comment: I'll test it soon, then I'll be back with news

Comment: Still not working, but now is for other reason, I edited the post with details of what's going on.

Comment: I see. You are not using the section that you created, but the generic one. Use ConfigurationSection configToEdit = config.createSection

Comment: I made the changes, the yml file is correct now, but now is giving me an error when I type /info get, to call restoreData method, I'll edit the post with the  error.

Comment: That's the same in restore method because you didn't use getted config section

Comment: Actually I  did it, I'll edit  the post with  the code updated.

Comment: You are creating a new one section when restoring, instead of using `getConfigurationSection`. Do you know what you are doing ? What's your main langage ?

Comment: Oh, I saw the error. Well, I think I know  what I'm doing. My main language is portuguese, Again, I apologize for my English. 

I edited my  code and the error is over, but the item still without enchantment.

Comment: No problem. It's just that i think you don't fully understand what you are doing. And if you were french, maybe I would explain you everything. Are you sure enchants well applied

Comment: I'm reading  the code here and what I think that is going  on is that the "List<String> enchants = configToEdit.getStringList("meta.enchants");" returns me null. I did some tests debuging, and when I try to print in console or chat, returns me "[]".

Comment: But your yaml well contains enchants ? Also, enchants don't have to be added with itemMeta ?

Comment: Yeah, contains  enchants, I edited the post with new pic of the file.  Well, I don't know if enchants have to be added with itemMeta, I tried add with "meta.addEnchant(Enchantment.getByName(split[0]), Integer.parseInt(split[1]),  true);" But, nothing too

Comment: Firstly, try to don't add image for data like that. Copy/paste into your question. Then, you didn't right the good name. You save "meta.enchant" and you try to get "meta.enchantS". Just remove the s and it's fine. Sorry it's a typo issue in my answer. I will fix it

Comment: Oh man, thank you  so  much, it worked. This is not what I need yet, 'cause now I need to identify the item in a sign, but I think that I can work with this. Ps: Don't need to add "item.addEnchantment", only "meta.addEnchant" and next: item.setItemMeta(meta);. Again, Thank you so much bro ;P

Comment: "need to identify item in a sign" you just have to know which sign correspond to which item. So you can do it with x/y/z position. But if you are really stick (after try something), just ask a new question :) And no problem, with pleasure ! Now you can set my answer as accepted !

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'll ask a new question later, I'm tired, two days trying to resolve this. My ideia was to do something like the /iinfo the ChestShop plugin, do you  know? I wan't to do this, just for learn, 'cause I can use others ways to get it, I think.

Comment: You can't get the plugin itself ?

Comment: Yes I can,  but I want to know  how it works to undertand the logic and method :P